# Subfolder for website on Mac OS X

Tags: php, apache, macos

I would like to run a local PHP (5.3) website on Mac OS X 10.6.  I have PHP configured properly and can access a website using http://mymac.local/~me/index.html.  I have this folder structure:

```
~me/Sites/index.html which points to http://mymac.local/~me/index.html
~me/Sites/mysite/home.html which doesn't work
```

If I try http://mymac.local/~me/mysite/home.html, I'll get a forbidden error stating I don't have permission to access that file.  If I put home.html in the Sites folder, I still get the error.   Seems Apache is hard wired to like only the index.html and no sub folders.  Is there a way to get that working?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new folder under ~me/Sites/ and see if that folder is accessible.
Permissions have been changed, you could chown or chmod the folder and files to get them back to being readable.

Comment: It is definitely permissions but I don't know how to change that on the Mac besides through "Get Info", which does no good.  The new subfolder produces the same forbidden results.  If I rename index.html (the one that works now) to home.html, that works fine.  So that file has some special permissions that all the others need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Sharing panel within System Preferences and make sure that File Sharing is turned on and that "Everyone" can Read your Sites folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't full understand your question. However, from experience I know that Apache on OS X can be a pain. You could dodge the problem and use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ran chmod -R 777 Sites and that solved it.